# finding change between records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I have a table where I am storing the stored number of barrels inside of many tanks.  I am storing values here every night at midnight, and at the beggining and end of any operator initiated transfer.

What I want to return is the number of barrels difference since the previous event record for that specific tank.  I have the correct ID for the self join to get the previous record number, however the barrels is incorrect.

Here is what I currently have.

```
SELECT
    inventory.id,
    MAX(inventory2.id) AS id2,
    inventory.tankname,
    inventory.barrels,
    inventory.eventstamp,
    inventory2.barrels
FROM 
    inventory
LEFT JOIN
    inventory inventory2 ON inventory2.tankname = inventory.tankname AND inventory2.eventstamp < inventory.eventstamp
GROUP BY
    inventory.id,
    inventory.tankname,
    inventory.barrels,
    inventory.eventstamp
ORDER BY
    inventory.tankname,
    inventory.eventstamp
```

That returns the following

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT i.*,
       (SELECT i2.id
        FROM inventory i2
        WHERE i2.tankname = i.tankname AND
              i2.eventstamp < i.eventstamp
        ORDER BY i2.eventstamp DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) as prev_id,
       (SELECT i2.barrels
        FROM inventory i2
        WHERE i2.tankname = i.tankname AND
              i2.eventstamp < i.eventstamp
        ORDER BY i2.eventstamp DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) as prev_barrels
FROM inventory i
ORDER BY i.tankname, i.eventstamp;
```

Your query doesn't work because you have columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY` and are not aggregated.  That shouldn't be allowed in any database; it is unfortunate that MySQL does allow it.

Comment: I didn't realize that you can reference parent columns in a sub query!